# how to extract a string from a list of strings from a parameter using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am getting a list of quoted strings back from AWS,
and I would like to isolate one of them into a parameter.

the command I am using is:

```
allelb=$(aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[].LoadBalancerName') &&  echo $allelb
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
[ "elb-app-mprest-dev", "elb-core-mprest-dev", "api-vector-k8s-local-0j8ccl", "a2e6a899d111011e897b0067693cf815", "api-clusters-sydney7-mpre-rqae1h" ]
```

What I want to do is, get only the string with the word 'sydney7' inside a parameter. So I will have a new parameter with this content inside :

**ELB=api-clusters-sydney7-mpre-rqae1h**

This is waht I got so far:

```
allelb=$(aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[].LoadBalancerName' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',' | tr -d ']' | tr -d '[') &&  echo $allelb | grep -o sydney7
```

but the output I get is not good enough-

```
sydney7
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Lots of ways...

Comment: I will edit the question to show the ways I tried

Comment: What if there's more than one such a string?

Comment: @choroba There will be no more than one from this string since this name is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cut

```
cut -d '"' -f10
```

with grep

```
grep -o '[^"]*sydney7[^"]*'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the output from your command is a JSON array, you should probably use a program for parsing and filtering JSON, like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.[] | match(".*sydney.*").string' <<< "$allelb"
"api-clusters-sydney7-mpre-rqae1h"
```

If you want it raw, use the `-r` flag:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | match(".*sydney.*").string' <<< "$allelb"
api-clusters-sydney7-mpre-rqae1h
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the assumption is that I can not install jq on my machine, I gave it a vote up :)